# Smooth scroll implementation causing entire section to float – issues with height or translation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I attempted to implement a smooth scroll effect for a specific section on my webpage using CSS and JavaScript. The smooth scrolling works as intended, but I've encountered an unexpected problem – the entire section appears to be floating or behaving strangely. It seems like there might be an issue with the height or translation properties that I used. I want the scrolling to be smooth, but the section should behave as it does by default without any floating or odd behavior.

Here's a snippet of the CSS and JavaScript I used for the smooth scroll:

```
const bodys = document.body,
  jsScroll = document.getElementsByClassName("js-scroll")[0],
  height = jsScroll.getBoundingClientRect().height - 1,
  speed = 0.08;

var offset = 0;

bodys.style.height = Math.floor(height) + "px";

function smoothScroll() {
  offset += (window.pageYOffset - offset) * speed;

  var scroll = "translateY(-" + offset + "px) translateZ(0)";
  jsScroll.style.transform = scroll;

  raf = requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll);
}
smoothScroll();
```

```
       <div class="js-cont">
        <div class="js-scroll">
    <section id="hero" class="has-image">
   My content
    </section>
    
</div>
</div>
```